# Passing mock as argument in Golang test

Tags: unit-testing, go

This is the code I am testing

```
func listObjects(cli *client.Client, options clientOptions) ([]BlobObjects, error) {
    objects, err := cli.ListBlobObjects(...)
}
```

In my test setup I do this

```
type MockClient struct {
    MockListBlobObjects func() ([]BlobObjects, error)
}

func (m *MockClient) ListBlobObjects(....) ([]BlobObjects, error) {
    // return some mock response
}
```

And this is my test case

```
func TestBlobObjects(t *testing.T) {
    tests := map[string]struct {
        client         *MockClient
        ...
    }{
        "Test case 1": {
            client: &MockClient{
                MockListBlobObjects: ....,
            },
            ....
        },

      ....
   for testName, test := range tests {
      blobs, err := (test.client, clientOptions{})
      // make assertions here
   }
```

The problem is `test.client`. Compiler is telling me

```
cannot use test.client (variable of type *MockClient) as *client.Client value in argument to listObjects
```

My hope was I have a mock client and if I call the function under test, then the mock client passed will call the mocked `listObjects`. This is how I would do in Python.

What should I do in Golang?

Comment: What is `client.Client`? What is the signature of the function under test? Too much code has been elided here to tell what the issue is, but most likely you're using a concrete type when you need to use an interface to do mocking.

Comment: @Adrian it's a third party sdk. The signature is exactly the same as the `MockClient`. I understand the brievty concern but it's too verbose. So I instantiate a 3rd party sdk, gets a client object and calls one of the public methods. That's pretty it. I want to call the mock client object so i can return a mock response of the public method i am calling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a common interface, which will be implemented by both types

```golang
type Client interface {
    ListBlobObjects func() ([]BlobObjects, error)
}

type RealClient struct {
}

func (c *RealClient) ListBlobObjects(....) ([]BlobObjects, error) {
    // return some response
}

type MockClient struct {
  // note: don't put method signature in function body
}

func (m *MockClient) ListBlobObjects(....) ([]BlobObjects, error) {
    // return some mock response
}
```

and then

```golang
var client client.Client
client = &RealClient{}
// or
client = &MockClient{}
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, I don't own the RealClient. It is a third party SDK. I can only import RealClient. I *can* create a type MyRealClient struct but there are over 30+ export methods I will be calling and seems like a bit anti-pattern to create one that just returns. So for me I instatnitate RealClient, passing it to the function listBlobObject (which handles a variety of blob objects)

Comment: Do you have control about usages of `RealClient`? If not (e.g. functions/methods from external module expect to receive `*RealClient`) then you cannot do anything. If yes then specify your own interface (like me with the `Client`) and use it everywhere. In go you don't have to specify interface in the same module as in a different languages and it is a common pattern to create an interface for external type to allow mocking